# Is there an MNIST dataset where the digits are in colour?

Tags: colors, mnist, digits

I would like to use the MNIST dataset, where each digit is assigned a specific colour. Not the background, the digit itself.

The following dataset colours the background of the image: https://www.wouterbulten.nl/blog/tech/getting-started-with-gans-2-colorful-mnist/

Comment: This work has MNIST with coloured digits: https://github.com/feidfoe/learning-not-to-learn/

The dataloader part in their code generates these images using masks I think: https://github.com/feidfoe/learning-not-to-learn/blob/master/data_loader.py

You can give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for the coloured MNIST dataset?

I have seen two papers proposing it:

- Invariant Risk Minimisation: [source code to generate the data](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InvariantRiskMinimization/blob/master/code/colored_mnist/main.py)
- PREDICTING WITH HIGH CORRELATION FEATURES: [source code to generate
  the data](https://github.com/salesforce/corr_based_prediction/blob/master/gen_color_mnist.py)